# Remove first level of escape in json String (Java)

Tags: java, json, string

I have a String like this:

```java
private String jsonString = "{\\\"test\\\":\\\"value \\\\\\\"ciao\\\\\\\"  \\\"}"
```

At runtime this should be: `{\"test\":\"value \\\"ciao\\\"  \"}`

Now I want to remove the only the first level of escape and leaving the nested escape.

The result should be:
`{"test":"value \"ciao\"  "}`

How can I do this? Is it possible with methods like `replace()` or `replaceAll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *[String#translateEscapes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#translateEscapes())* method.

```java
String s = "{\\\"test\\\":\\\"value \\\\\\\"ciao\\\\\\\"  \\\"}";
s = s.translateEscapes();
```

Output

```
{"test":"value \"ciao\"  "}
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain me how this works?

Comment: @PaoloMossini, have a look at the _JavaDoc_.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` like this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = "{\\\"test\\\":\\\"value \\\\\\\"ciao\\\\\\\"  \\\"}";

        String unescapedString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\").replaceAll("\\\\\\\"", "\"");

        System.out.println(unescapedString);
    }
}
```